# Rails find where substraction is minimum between two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two fields in my database:

```
submitted_values
max_values
```

How can I find the row where the difference between `max_values - submitted_values` is minimum using AR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do the trick.

```
Model.order('submitted_values - max_values').limit(1)
```

Comment: I would add explicit ordering to avoid confusion whether this returns max or min ;)

Comment: @KonradOleksiuk What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant putting ASC or DESC.